# Release build runs differently when setting debuggable to false

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio, in **Module Settings -> Build Types**, *debuggable* is set to *false*. I ran the release version like this and now my program behaves differently, and doesn't work the way I want it to. A curious thing though, is when I run the same release version but with *debuggable* set to *true*, the program behaves normally (the way I originally built the program when the build variant was set to debug).

Why is my program behaving like this?

In my original debug build, the game's entire screen has an `ImageView` which responds to `onTouch` events. In the `onTouch` method, it first checks if user input is enabled and if so, handles it (this doesnt seem to be working at some point)

Build gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.dark_maze_signature
        debuggable false
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:2.2.0.0'
    implementation('com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:5.3.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:vungle:5.3.2.1'
}
```

Comment: You should at least describe your app, any third party libraries you include and actually tell us what behavior is different.

Comment: @MorrisonChang added code